# Error: identifier "LCD_E_PORT" is undefined

Tags: c

Why I get the error: **identifier "LCD_E_PORT" is undefined** in this code:

```
#include <msp430f5438a.h>
#include "IO_functions.h"
#define LCD_E_PORT   PORT_6
#define LCD_E        PIN_4

#include "LCD1602.h"

int main(void)
{
WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;      // Stop watchdog timer
P4DIR = 0x03;
P4OUT = 0x00;

output_bit(PORT_4, PIN_7, 1);
output_bit(PORT_4, PIN_7, 0);
lcd_send_nibble(0x0f);

while(1)
{
  P4OUT ^= BIT0;
  __delay_cycles(500000);
}
}
```

Since I have defined LCD_E_PORT at the top of my code I don't understand where this error comes from.

This is LCD1602.c in which I am using LCD_E_PORT:

```
#include <msp430f5438a.h>
#include "LCD1602.h"
#include "IO_functions.h"


void lcd_send_nibble(unsigned char nibble)
{
   output_bit(LCD_DB4_PORT, LCD_DB4, !!(nibble & 1));
   output_bit(LCD_DB5_PORT, LCD_DB5, !!(nibble & 2));
   output_bit(LCD_DB6_PORT, LCD_DB6, !!(nibble & 4));
   output_bit(LCD_DB7_PORT, LCD_DB7, !!(nibble & 8));
   __delay_cycles(8);
   output_bit(LCD_E_PORT, LCD_E, 1);
   __delay_cycles(16);
   output_bit(LCD_E_PORT, LCD_E, 0);
 }

void lcd_send_byte(unsigned char data_instr, unsigned char data)
{
   output_bit(LCD_RS_PORT, LCD_RS, 0);
   __delay_cycles(480);
   if(data_instr == DATA)
      output_bit(LCD_RS_PORT, LCD_RS, 1);
   else
      output_bit(LCD_RS_PORT, LCD_RS, 0);
   __delay_cycles(8);
   output_bit(LCD_E_PORT, LCD_E, 0);
   lcd_send_nibble(data >> 4);
   lcd_send_nibble(data & 0x0F);
}

void lcd_init(void)
{
   unsigned char i;
   output_bit(LCD_RS_PORT, LCD_RS, 0);
   output_bit(LCD_E_PORT, LCD_E, 0);
   __delay_cycles(120000);
   for(i=0 ;i < 3; i++)
   {
      lcd_send_nibble(0x03);
      __delay_cycles(25000);
   }
   lcd_send_nibble(0x02);
   lcd_send_byte(INSTR, 0x28);
   __delay_cycles(25000);
   lcd_send_byte(INSTR, 0x0C);
   __delay_cycles(25000);
   lcd_send_byte(INSTR, 0x01);
   __delay_cycles(25000);
   lcd_send_byte(INSTR, 0x06);
    __delay_cycles(25000);
   }
```

Comment: By any chance are you using `LCD_E_PORT` in `"IO_functions.h"`?

Comment: Nope. The error appears in `LCD1602.c`

Comment: BTW, you don't seem to use `LCD_E_PORT` anywhere. then what's the purpose of having it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Y7MPFIDn9dNEhrcWVlQk4xYk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: huh, cannot access. behind a firewall. Please post the related code here itself.

Comment: Please makle use of tge "edit" feature in the question itself and add the relevant info there, not in comments.

Comment: Apologize I am new in this forum.

Comment: No need to apologize. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the updated code, the definition of `LCD_E_PORT` is not visible from `LCD1602.c` file.

You might want to add the `#define` in the header file (`LCD1602.h` or any other, at your choice) itself which will be included in all the source files making use of the macro.

Comment: I have commented that line since I want to change the macro from my source code.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Y7MPFIDn9dXzJUNEZRWi1vSUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow Once again, I cannot see your link. However, please understand, you cannot change macro value at runtime. it can only be manipulated in compile-time. If you want the later, cosider using `#ifdef` and `#undef` directtives, too.